# image passed as props react native not showing

Tags: react-native, expo

i get image url correct and passed as props but image not showing in my app

**main screen**
here main screen that render FlatList data = products that include image url and i log that and getting correct but image not showing
    const products = useSelector(state => state.products.availableProducts);

```
return(

<FlatList numColumns ={2}
  data={products}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  renderItem={itemData => (
    <ProductItem
      image={itemData.item.imageUrl}
      title={itemData.item.title}
      price={itemData.item.price}
      onSelect={()=>{
        props.navigation.navigate('detail', {
          productId: itemData.item.id,
        })
      }}
    >
    </ProductItem>
  )}
/>
```

**ProductItem component**

```
<View style={style.product}> 
  <View style={style.touchable}>
    <TouchableCmp onPress={props.onSelect} useForeground>
      <View>
        <View style={style.imageContainer}>
          <Image style={style.image} source={{uri: props.image}} />
        </View>
        <View style={style.detail}>

          <Text style={style.title}>{props.title}</Text>
          <Text style={style.price}>{props.price}SDG</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableCmp>
    <View style={{marginTop:1}}>{props.delete}</View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: 2 questions: what is in your uri and what type of image is it?

Comment: show me your image prop.

Comment: this image url 
shlel-mustafa.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/images/oWJDjP3LQn.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the should add http:// to image url because i am not adding when saving data 
code will be like

```
<Image style={styles.image} source= 
{{uri:`http://${singleproduct.imageUrl}`}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

¿What properties does the style tag "style.image" have?
There may be a problem with the height or width of the image.