# Why does Nuxt3 not resolve URLs passed as props to a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have this Vue component, ProductPanel.vue, to render products:

```
<template>
    <div class="product-panel">
        <h2 class="text-center text-primary">
            <slot name="product-name"></slot>
        </h2>
        <img src="~/assets/image.png" alt="test (works)" style="border: thin solid red;"/>
        <img :src="logoUrl" alt="product logo (doesn't work)" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
    logoUrl: String
});

onMounted(() => {
    console.log('Logo URL:', props.logoUrl);
});

</script>
```

And I have been testing it like this:

```
  <ProductPanel logoUrl="~/assets/image.png">
    <template #product-name>Flux capacitor</template>
  </ProductPanel>
```

The logo is displayed by test img tag, but is not displayed when the same URL is passed in `logoUrl` as a prop. On the console, I see `GET http://localhost:3002/reports/~/assets/icons/heart.png 404 (Page not found: /reports/~/assets/icons/heart.png)`.

[image passed as props react native not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410005/image-passed-as-props-react-native-not-showing) seems related, but is for React and doesn't (to me) suggest a solution.

I suspect that the issue is that the image has not been `required`, but I'm not sure of the best way to resolve this. I could `require` images in `data` (e.g., `data () { logoUrl: require('@/assets/image.png') }`) and then pass that, but I'm hoping that there's a shorthand that obviates the maintenance overhead of that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to import the image and bind it to the prop :

```html
<script setup>
 import img from '~/assets/image.png'
</script>
<template>
  <ProductPanel :logo-url="img">
    <template #product-name>Flux capacitor</template>
  </ProductPanel>
</template>
```

or place it inside the public folder and use its path directly.

Comment: I ended up putting it in the public folder, which works well.